# Display and Expression Views are giving errors

Tags: eclipse, grails, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I am using SpringSource Tool Suite 2.9.2 and Grails 2.0.3. I am trying to use the Expressions and Display windows, but both are giving me errors.

The Expression Window says:

> org.eclipse.debug.core.DebugException:
>   com.sun.jdi.ObjectCollectedException occurred retrieving type

This message is different sometimes and says it could not get the right types as if I didn't include packages.

The Display Window says:

> "Evaluation failed. Reason(s): An exception occurred durring
>   evaluation."

Anyone have any idea what is going on?

EDIT: 
Andrew, all of those items in the Preferences were checked with the exception of "Enable extra Groovy debug support on *all* projects (not just Groovy projects)." which I checked.

I still get the error, and for some reason nothing is showing up in the log, but the Expressions opens a sub window that says:

> See error log: startup failed:
>   *_*_Eval.groovy: 7: unable to resolve class mydomain.User  @ line 7, column 23.    import mydomain.User;
>                         ^
>
> 1 error

Something that is probably relevant: This import is the 3rd domain import on the page. The other two that look like they are working are in the "domain" folder in my "grails-app" folder, but the one that is not working is in "src/groovy" as the project is using Hibernate.xml files. I would expect the Expressions to work for either, but maybe this is the problem?

Comment: With groovy, expressions and display never worked for me as they work with java. They fails for most of cases. inspect isn't that good either

Comment: I'm seeing this exact issue, but intermittently.  Some breakpoints have Expressions working, others all Expressions fail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several things that you need to do before debug evaluations can work in Groovy.  Most of the time, these things are configured automatically, but sometimes you need to do one or two things manually.

1. Go to Preferences -> JDT Weaving, make sure it is enabled
2. Go to Preferences -> Groovy -> Debugger -> Extended debugging.  Make sure that all check boxes are selected.

If you are still getting this exception, then this may be a bug.  Please update your question with the full stack trace from the error log (Window -> Show view -> Other -> Error log).  Also, include the code snippet that you are evaluating.

Comment: was there a bug report filed on this?

Comment: It's likely that this was the problem described above: https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS-2499  It is now fixed and available in 3.0.0.M2.

Comment: I couldn't enable JDT Weaving (not even manually) until I installed STS plugin (AJDT and OSGi packages). Then I got JDT Weaving automatically enabled and Display view worked great.